# ajax reload with custom template

Tags: theming, forms, ajax

i have a custom template for a custom module block. here is the one select box

```
$form['calculator']['state_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t("State"),
    '#default_value' =>  $state_select_options_selected,
    //'#default_value' =>  'Please Select',
    '#options' => $state_select_options ,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="state-select-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'calculator_state_select_ajax_callback',
        // 'wrapper' => 'state-select-replace',
    ),
);
```

and here is the template function

```
function calculator_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
 $themes = array(
'calculator_form' => array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'template' => 'calculator_block',
  //'path' => $path . '/templates',
),
);
 return $themes;
 }
```

im displaying the form like this

```
print drupal_render_children($form['calculator']['state_select']);
```

the problem is that with the template the form ajax call does not work.

Comment: have u tried it like this drupal_render_children($form['calculator']);

Comment: that will print the entire form and the ajax does not work still.